# How to compute distribution from conditional distribution and mixed random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $ X, Y $ be random variables with $ X $ being continuous and density function $ f $. Suppose $ Y / X = x $ ($ Y $ conditioned to $ X = x $) has a Poisson distribution of parameter $ \lambda $. How can I compute the distribution of $ Y $? I am stuck with this type of problems, that mix continuous and discrete types.

Comment: What is $\lambda$? Is that You meant Poisson distribution with parameter $x$? Presumably then, $X$ is a non-negative random variable? Well, anyway, one way to tackle such problems is to use $\mathbb E[Z] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[Z|\mathcal G]]$ for any integrable $Z$ and any $\sigma-$field $\mathcal G$. Here, use it with $Z = 1_{\{Y \le t\}}$ and $\mathcal G = \sigma(X)$, i.e. we'll calculating the CDF of $Y$ via $\mathbb P(Y \le t) = \mathbb E[1_{\{Y \le t\}}] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[1_{\{Y \le t\}} | X]] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb P(Y \le t | X)]$.